# Open with Access Link Disabled in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I m trying to access a list in SharePoint online on IE. I am able to do an export to excel, but Open with Access is not enabled. I m the site collection admin and Global Admin. It was working earlier, for the same list.
I m using Office 2016 64 bit, Windows 7 and SharePoint Online and using IE 11 browser.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked all lists in your site? Does this issue only occur on the specific list?

You can try the following troubleshooting steps to resolve the “Open with Access” button is not enabled issue:

1. Check whether ActiveX control (OWSSUPP.dll) is disabled. Enable it.
2. Add the site to the trusted sites.
3. Are you using 64-bit IE? Check the 32-bit IE.
4. Check if it is cause by a IE add-on.
5. Try with 32-bit Office and compare the results.
6. Check in another machine to see if you can reproduce it.
7. Repair your office.

Comment: This issue happens to all the list in my machine. However, it works fine in another machine for my same login. This is specific to IE or the windows update that would have happen.

Comment: Have you tried the steps?

Comment: yes i did and same issue.

Comment: Do you have custom installation of Office product?